# What is the order of assigning managed bean's properties?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

When form is being submitting, what is the order of assigning values? In the form:

```
<h:form>
    <h:inputText id="username" value="#{registrationBean.username}"
    <h:inputText id="password" value="#{registrationBean.password}"
    <h:commandLink id="register" action="#{registrationBean.doRegister}"
</h:form>
```

Now, we have managed bean:

```
public class RegistrationBean{

    private String username;
    private String password;

    //GET, SET

    public void doRegister(){

        //Some staff

    }
}
```

I presume that JSF always performs assignation with respect to the order we put the elements in markup.

So in my case `username` field will be initialized first, and `password` will be initialized second.

Can I rely on that order? Is it standartized or implementation-defined feature?

By initialization I mean invokation of the corresponding setter method.

Comment: @JaqenH'ghar I don't understand your question. I asked about the order because it would simplify the solution of the problem in my case.

Comment: @JaqenH'ghar So is it reliable to do so? Or the JSF spec doesn't mention it explicitly?

Comment: @JaqenH'ghar Yes, we shouldn't. But I have a dilemma: rewrite tons of code from scratch or rely on that feature.

Comment: @JaqenH'ghar That's why I asked about that.

Comment: @JaqenH'ghar Couldn't you just say yes or no? Why do you ask me all this questions?

Comment: In any such cases, trace the JSF life cycle using a `PhaseListener`. It passes through several phases in between through validator(s)/converter too, if any.

Comment: This is a HUGE [XY-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You're going totally the wrong way in an attempt to solve your underlying problem.

Comment: @BalusC Of course not, my question doesn't realte to that problem. I asked about a specific part of JSF working principle which is ontopic here.

Comment: @BalusC BTW, I mentioned the underlying problem because just to make you know what I'm trying to solve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you may know JSF Request Processing Lifecycle applies to a View. Views are represented by a data structure rooted in an instance of javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot, and identified by a view identifier, which is normally a context-relative path of the web application resource (your .xhtml page). Being constructed from xhtml page UIViewRoot points to a tree of the same structure.

Application model data update is performed during the Update Model Values phase. It's when your setters are called. All operations during this phase are performed on a UIViewRoot. From the [JSF specification](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr314/index2.html):

> During the Update Model Values phase, the JSF implementation must call the 
>   processUpdates() method of the UIViewRoot component of the tree.
>   This will normally cause the processUpdates() method of each component in the tree to be called recursively, as described in the API reference for the UIComponent.processUpdates() method.

This means that as long as your application doesn't interact with UIComponents of the View directly the order of the component processing will be determined by your xhtml markup.

Comment: What do you mean doesn't interact with UIComponents directly? Couldn't you show the example of such interaction?

Comment: You are able to acquire UIViewRoot component associated with the current request from FacesContext by invoking FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot(). This allows you to perform some direct interactions with the UIComponent tree, such as adding new components to the view, removing them, or modifying the attributes and properties of existing components.See [UIViewRoot docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UIViewRoot.html) for more info.

Comment: You mean accessing UIViewRoot programmatically, huh? So, the order is reliable if we don't perform anything with UIViewRoot instance in Java. Is that what you mean? If so, thank you, I got that.

Comment: Can I put FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().processUpdates(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()); into the page controller to get the form to submit?

Answer (score 3):

It is very likely that each phase of the JSF lifecycle processes the components in document order (i.e. same order as the tags appear in the .xhtml file).

Nevertheless, I recommend to not rely on this, because it is unexpected for a future maintainer of your code that the order of tags has a functional impact. That is, if some future change request calls for a different tag order, the maintainer is likely to change the tag order without expecting this to cause a bug ...